# Convert amount to word in Python In Indian Format

Tags: python

How to convert amount to word in Indian?

I was using num2words library but its is presenting wrong set of words while presenting 'lakhs' and 'crores'.

For example:

`num2words(903614.55, lang='en-IN')`
Its printing `'nine hundred and three thousand, six hundred and fourteen point five five'`

But actual Indian Amount Presentation should be `nine lakhs three thousand six hundred fourteen and five five paisa`.

Then I tried the below code:

```
def num2words(num):
    under_20 = ['Zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Eleven','Twelve','Thirteen','Fourteen','Fifteen','Sixteen','Seventeen','Eighteen','Nineteen']
    tens = ['Twenty','Thirty','Forty','Fifty','Sixty','Seventy','Eighty','Ninety']
    above_100 = {100: 'Hundred',1000:'Thousand', 100000:'Lakhs', 10000000:'Crores'}

    if num < 20:
         return under_20[num]

    if num < 100:
        return tens[(int)(num/10)-2] + ('' if num%10==0 else ' ' + under_20[num%10])

    # find the appropriate pivot - 'Million' in 3,603,550, or 'Thousand' in 603,550
    pivot = max([key for key in above_100.keys() if key <= num])

    return num2words((int)(num/pivot)) + ' ' + above_100[pivot] + ('' if num%pivot==0 else ' ' + num2words(num%pivot))
```

But now an error is coming

> TypeError : list indices must be integers or slices, not decimal.Decimal

My problem is with decimal numbers, Integer is working fine.

Comment: casting to int in python would be just `int(variable)`

Comment: You mean to say `(int)` will be just `int`

Comment: can you give the number on which it is failing

Comment: for me it giving correct result in python3

Comment: Try this number  `650958.32`

Comment: updated the answer, kindly check

Comment: en_IN, not en-IN for num2words lang argument. This will fix it. See my answer below.

Comment: I think this code was written by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could just cast it on the first line if you're not handling decimals.
You can also use // to do integer division.

```
import decimal    

def num2words(num):
    num = decimal.Decimal(num)
    decimal_part = num - int(num)
    num = int(num)

    if decimal_part:
        return num2words(num) + " point " + (" ".join(num2words(i) for i in str(decimal_part)[2:]))

    under_20 = ['Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen', 'Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen', 'Nineteen']
    tens = ['Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Forty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninety']
    above_100 = {100: 'Hundred', 1000: 'Thousand', 100000: 'Lakhs', 10000000: 'Crores'}

    if num < 20:
        return under_20[num]

    if num < 100:
        return tens[num // 10 - 2] + ('' if num % 10 == 0 else ' ' + under_20[num % 10])

    # find the appropriate pivot - 'Million' in 3,603,550, or 'Thousand' in 603,550
    pivot = max([key for key in above_100.keys() if key <= num])

    return num2words(num // pivot) + ' ' + above_100[pivot] + ('' if num % pivot==0 else ' ' + num2words(num % pivot))


print(num2words(decimal.Decimal("650958.32")))
# Six Lakhs Fifty Thousand Nine Hundred Fifty Eight point Three Two
```

Comment: What I should do if I want to handle decimal?Actually my question is that only?

Comment: what should be the expected output for 1.55 for example?

Comment: see the updated answer, is the result what you need?

Comment: ecimal_part = num - int(num) operation could fail this with num=5.1

Comment: That's because of floating-point calculation, the number passed in needs to be decimal.Decimal("5.1")

Comment: I guess we could change the first line to `num = decimal.Decimal(str(num))` to avoid the problem. but I'm not sure if that's required here.

Comment: en_IN, not en-IN for num2words lang argument. @rabbit.aaron

Answer (score 5):

The solution is simple, and the mistake is obvious in hindsight.

Just replace en-IN with en_IN in your call to num2words. There is no need for any custom code. I was burnt by this too.

```
num2words.num2words(123456, lang='en_IN')
```

returns

```
one lakh, twenty-three thousand, four hundred and fifty-six
```

Answer (score 1):

you can split the decimal and fractional part can call num2word function twice on number and other on fractional part

```
import math
def num2words(num):
    under_20 = ['Zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Eleven','Twelve','Thirteen','Fourteen','Fifteen','Sixteen','Seventeen','Eighteen','Nineteen']
    tens = ['Twenty','Thirty','Forty','Fifty','Sixty','Seventy','Eighty','Ninety']
    above_100 = {100: 'Hundred',1000:'Thousand', 100000:'Lakhs', 10000000:'Crores'}

    if num < 20:
         return under_20[(int)(num)]

    if num < 100:
        return tens[(int)(num/10)-2] + ('' if num%10==0 else ' ' + under_20[(int)(num%10)])

    # find the appropriate pivot - 'Million' in 3,603,550, or 'Thousand' in 603,550
    pivot = max([key for key in above_100.keys() if key <= num])

    return num2words((int)(num/pivot)) + ' ' + above_100[pivot] + ('' if num%pivot==0 else ' ' + num2words(num%pivot))

num="5.12"
print(num2words(int(num.split(".")[0])))
print(num2words(int(num.split(".")[1])))
```

https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/J7zsZyIT6m