# Number string to words string in Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble in converting string to integer in python

Here is my code:

```
n=['33','12','45']
for i in range(len(n)):
    if n[i]=='33':
        print('thirty three')
    if n[i]=='12':
        print('twelve')
    if n[i]=='45':
        print('forty five')
```

This code is running well, but I want a shorter code if there will be more numbers like these, that will be converted from string to integer.

Please help :)

Comment: You could use two lists and then run them parallel in a loop. For example: `l1 = ["one","two","three"] l2= ["1","2","3"] for value, number in zip(l1,l2): print(number)` Does that answer your question?

Comment: What is the output that you expect for '1243884' ?

Comment: @mozilla_firefox twelve lakh forty three thousand eight hundred eighty four. Is it possible ?

Comment: yes it's possible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58486823/convert-amount-to-word-in-python-in-indian-format it is over here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@big buddy Simplest way to go about solving your problem is using a package called [num2words](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/) using `pip install num2words`.

Then you can just pass the integer as an argument to `num2words()`. In your case, it will be

```
n=['33','12','45']
for i in range(len(n)):
    print(num2words(n[i]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`inflect`](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) module:

```
>>> import inflect
>>> p = inflect.engine()
>>> p.number_to_words(33)
thirty-three
```

The `inflect` module can convert any number to their word representatives.

To install the `inflect` module do the below in your command prompt:

```
pip install inflect
```

So in your example code you should do:

```
n = ['33', '12', '45']
p = inflect.engine()
for i in n:
    print(p.number_to_words(int(i)))
```

Output:

```
thirty-three
twelve
forty-five
```